# How can I remote unlock my RHEL7 workstation?

Tags: rhel, gnome3, screensaver

I have just upgraded my workstation from RHEL 6 with Gnome 2 to RHEL 7 with Gnome 3 Classic.

Since I can unlock my Windows Laptop with its fingerprint reader, and both are networked, I got used to unlocking my Linux Workstation by running a batch file on the Windows machine which ssh'ed to the Linux box and ran `gnome-screensaver-command -d`.

Having moved to RHEL 7, I find that `gnome-screensaver-command` is no longer available, and so far I have failed to find any way to replicate this functionality.

So, what is the equivalent of `gnome-screensaver-command -d` in RHEL 7/Gnome 3?

Comment: I don't know much about gnome, but this might be a breadcrumb: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Screensaver

Comment: Gnome 3 removed the gnome-screensaver daemon.  Now the screen lock is actually started by GDM when you log in, and isn't a separate executable.  Its possible to send dbus messages at it but as far as I can tell, no way to actually tell it to unlock if its locked with a password.